# What is $(2018^{2019} + 2019^{2018}) \pmod{7}$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The solution should be within a page and please give full explanation.

The original question is,

What is $$\left(2018^{2019} + 2019^{2018}\right) \pmod{7} ?$$

Comment: **Hint:** What are $2019 \pmod{7}$ and $2018 \pmod{7}$?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Please explain why you can replace the bases 2018 and 2019 with 2 and 3. Then try to solve this for simpler cases. You could start with $2^3 \mod 7$ and then you should pause and think.

Comment: Are you familiar with Fermat's little theorem?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

$$2^3\equiv 1\pmod 7$$ and $$3^3\equiv -1\pmod 7$$